# A possible way to redirect the user to a page on window.unload event, all on the same domain

Tags: php, jquery, http, redirect

I am using PHP and Jquery. This is quite difficult to explain so I shall try and be as clear as I can

1. User is on domain www.test.com/testb
2. User then redirects to www.test.com
3. If this happens then I need it to somehow redirect to www.test.com/void

So far I have a window.unload event, and windows location, but it dosent redirect.

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
    window.location = "http://www.test.com/void";

});
```

The aim is to build a online test and if the user redirects away while taking the test it redirects to a void page saying that the user has failed the test.

Comment: I'd check a session variable. Set the variable on completed test. Check it in test.com - if not set, redirect. This only works on pages that you control.

Comment: Wouldn't it be really annoying if you couldn't leave websites when typing an adress in the browser or just shutting down the window, instead you'd get redirected to random ad sites and other crap. There's a reason you can't do this, but if you control `test.com` you can redirect users coming ***into*** that site of their own **free will**, and you could even check the referrer to see where they are coming from.

Comment: I dont mind if the user leaves the site altogether to another domain, but if they redirect to another page on the site, then I want to display a page to say so.

Comment: cookies ..............

Comment: Why would leaving the site = failing the test?  What if their browser dies mid test? You should be using a time period and if they don't complete in that time, fail.  Not fail if your browser dies and you have to come back: that's evil.

Comment: what if they open another site in a new tab? or another browser?

Comment: I know a lot of testing sites that do this @developerwjk and you're right, *it's evil*.

Comment: @adeneo, It used to be like that in like IE3 as I recall.  And man it was annoying!

Comment: I was trying to find a method to prevent a user going back in the test and redoing questions, skipping the test and redoing the same one. What design would be the best to accommodate this?

Comment: So what do you see on other sites, for instance the one you are on now, jsFiddle etc. they have a simple confirm asking if you really want to leave and loose the changes you've made, and that's as good as it gets.

Comment: @MatthewUnderwood if only you asked that in the first place